# Getting an instance of a cycle in a directed graph

Tags: algorithms, graph-theory

(I asked the same question in stackoverflow, but thought that this website might be the another good place to ask this.)

I want an algorithm that gives one instance of a cycle in a directed graph if there is any. Can anyone show me a direction maybe in pseudo-code?

I implemented [Kahn's (1962) algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) in Ruby that detects if a graph has a cycle, but I want to know not only whether it has a cycle, but also one possible instance of such cycle.

```
example_graph = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [6, 2]]
```

**Kahn's algorithm**

```
def cyclic?(graph)
  ## The set of edges that has not been examined
  graph = graph.dup
  n, m = graph.transpose
  ## The set of nodes that are the supremum in the graph
  sup = (n - m).uniq
  while sup_old = sup.pop do
    sup_old = graph.select{|n, _| n == sup_old}
    graph -= sup_old
    sup_old.each {|_, ssup| sup.push(ssup) unless graph.any?{|_, n| n == ssup}}
  end
  !graph.empty?
end
```

The above algorithm tells whether a graph has a cycle:

```
cyclic?(example_graph) #=> true
```

but I want not only that but an example of a cycle like this:

```
#=> [[2, 3], [3, 6], [6, 2]]
```

If I were to output the variable `graph` of the above code at the end of examination, it will give:

```
#=> [[2, 3], [3, 4], [3, 5], [3, 6], [6, 2]]
```

which includes the cycle I want, but it also includes extra edges that are irrelevant to the cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Tarjan's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm) to look for strongly connected components. When you find a component with more than one node in it, it will be defined by one or more edges in the depth-first tree; such a back edge together with a path from one end to another in the depth-first tree is a cycle.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the best way to do it.